# Run an apple script saved as run only so icon doesnt show in dock

Tags: applescript

I created an apple script and placed on my desktop. I first saved it as .app and when double clicked it ran code successfully and closed. However in the time it would run it would show an icon in my dock.

So to avoid that i thought lets save it as a run only script. So I did that but now when I double click it, it doesn't run the script, it just says 'it was saved as read only and cannot open'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the `Contents/Info.plist` (easy with Xcode) located in the app bundle and add a `Application is agent (UIElement)` - Key with value `YES` to it. Now it shouldn't show in the Dock when running.

The raw text to include is:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a `.app` for this? I just right clicked and opened it up and i see the info.plist and it seems editable.

Comment: Awesome! This worked for a `.app` thanks! I just right clicked, clicked "Show Contents" and added this to the `info.plist`

Answer (score 1):

Change your run only script's extension from "`.scpt`" to "`.app`" and you should be able to run the thing.

More information can be found in [this closely related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38761/how-to-run-a-downloaded-run-only-applescript).

Comment: However that `.app` makes it an extension :( Which makes the icon appear in the dock while its running :( That was the first thing i tried.

Comment: Ah that topic says to drag it to scripts folder and then enalbe script menu bar. But dragging to scripts folder requires admin password huh? :(